# Memory Leak, Re-assigning NSArray Property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a `UITableView` backed by an `NSArray` property.  The Array is declared as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *events;

@synthesize events;
```

And used in the following methods.  Instruments keeps telling me that populateEvents is causing leaks.  I have tried numerous variations of this code but keep ending up with either more leaks or `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.events = [self populateEvents];
    }

    - (void)updateData
    {   
        events = nil;
        self.events = [self populateEvents];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    - (NSArray*)populateEvents
    {
        NSMutableArray *response = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Event"];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement = [database prepare:sql];

        if(statement != nil)
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the response
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
                event.subject = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                e

                [response addObject:event];
                [event release];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        return [response autorelease];
    }
```

**UPDATE**
A Lot of you are asking about the event class:

```
@interface Event : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *details;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *startTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *endTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *eventType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *employee;

@end

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    [subject release];
    [details release];
    [startTime release];
    [endTime release];
    [eventType release];
    [employee release];
}



- (NSString*)startTime
{
    return [self humanReadableDate:startTime];
}



- (NSString*)endTime
{
    return [self humanReadableDate:endTime];
}



- (NSString*)humanReadableDate:(NSString*)isoDate
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:isoDate];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString* humanrReadable = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    return humanrReadable;
}
@end
```

Comment: What's the need for `events = nil` in your code?

Comment: If I dont autorelease response in populateEvents than there is no exc_bad_access but there is still the leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should release internal objects in `Events` class **before** calling `[super dealloc]`.

And remove that `events = nil;` in updateData method. It's unnecessary and will cause problems even after you fix the `Events` class.

Answer (score 4):

it's a leak because you change the pointer of your `NSArray` (events) to nil without releasing the previous object. You lost pointer to your previous array, hence a leak.

change your

```
events = nil;
```

to

```
self.events = nil;
```

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS if use self.events = nil

Comment: it shouldn't, really, it might be some other stuff that is causing it. Also, you can just remove that line all together, there is no need for that line of code.

Comment: X Slash is correct.  If you still experience problems, there are probably more bugs elsewhere in your code.  I'd hazard a guess that the `subject` property on the `Event` class is not declared as `retain` or `copy`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the line

```
event = nil;
```

Since your property is set to retain, event is point to nil without releasing previous memory.

You can just call `self.events = [self populateEvents];`
It will release the previous obj first before assign and retain the the obj.

Comment: Hi Hanon removing events = nil gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What is the structure in Event?

Answer (score 1):

Just Set this Environment Variable in your XCode project Groups and files pane,
you will find Executables -> Your Application -> Right Click -> Get Info -> Arguments Tab -> Environment Variables

Name : NSZombieEnabled 
Value : YES

This will help you to find the zombie object of your object if there is any object you are releasing more than once of accessing that value.

Best of Luck !